# How to get a solution involving logs in the right form?

Tags: equation-solving

How do I get

```
Solve[(1/9)^(r/2) == 1/n , r]
```

to give me

```
 Log[n]/Log[3]
```

and not

`-Log[1/n]/Log[3]`?

Comment: Thanks. Solve may have just been the wrong command.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Perhaps you should consider posting working answers, however short they may be, as answers and not as comments. The list of seemingly unanswered questions is  growing and growing. I won't hold it against you ;-)

Comment: You can get the result with `Solve`, you can do e.g. this `Simplify[ Solve[ (1/9)^(r/2) == 1/n, r, Reals], n > 0]`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries the alternative is someone collects all these answers in comments and produce 200 answers ;-)

Comment: Or I can answer my own question with the comments :)

Comment: @lip1 First register your account, then answer your own question and you'll get at least one upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it :

```
Reduce[(1/9)^(r/2) == 1/n && n > 0, r, Reals]

(* n > 0 && r == Log[n]/Log[3] *)
```